# Disable gdb highlight colors

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm using `gdb` on Fedora 32 and gdb prints information with highlight color.
However the color has less contrast for example dark blue text on black background.
How can I disable the highlight color?

Comment: Have you read thru the [gdb manual](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Styling.html)?

Comment: The manual is too long to read through everything. I searched several keyword such as `color` and `highlight` but couldn't find the settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `set style enabled off` to disable all styling.

Its possible to have more control over the output styling as described in the [manual](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Output-Styling.html). For example, to just change the blue address you could use `set style address foreground cyan`.